# Dynamicly increasing amount of tabs and pages in flexdashboards

Tags: r, flexdashboard

So I just started using flexdashboard to visualize my results and i have a critical question. In my procedure i have a dataset with 10 columns which updates everyday. In the end of the day I am reporting only the columns that are in a way significant.

The thing is that in some days I need to report 2 columns, and in some other 10 columns. So i was thinking to automate this in flexdashboard.

To define a new row with tabs we do (e.g for 2 tabs)

````
Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A
```{r}
one <- my_visualization function(data[,1])
```

### Chart B
```{r}
two <-  my_visualization function(data[,2])
```
````

Which creates a row with two tabs.

My question is: Is there any way to produce as many tabs as say a variable `c` indicates? (say `c=4`, i would want 4 tabs!)

Sorry if this has been answered before! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a script to generate the flexdashboard Rmd hen run the flexdashboard Rmd. You can use something like [`whisker`](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker) to make templates as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use the cat function. below is an outline. essentially it is a for loop with the day's plots with the inclusion of the two 'cat' calls. This approach allows for variable tab numbers to be generated. By adding {.tabset} this will make the display neater when there are many plots, instead of generating long documents. The '\n' are critical to create a new line, otherwise the hashtags don't work.

Hopefully you found this already. Just adding this for others.

`````
    # todays results (.tabset)
    
    ```{r}
    
    rlist <- c(columns to plot)

    for (r in rlist) {
      
      
      cat(paste0('## ', r, '\n'))
      
      
     # insert your plot
      
      cat'\n\n')
      
    }
    
    ````
`````